# In Swift, how efficient is it to append an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, append

If you have an array which can very in size throughout the course of your program, would it be more efficient to declare the array as the maximum size it will ever reach and then control how  much of the array your program can access, or to change the size of the array quite frequently throughout the course of the program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Swift headers](http://swifter.natecook.com/type/Array/), there's this about array growth and capacity:

> When an array's contiguous storage fills up, new storage must be allocated and elements must be moved to the new storage. Array, ContiguousArray, and Slice share an exponential growth strategy that makes append a constant time operation *when amortized over many invocations.* In addition to a `count` property, these array types have a `capacity` that reflects their potential to store elements without reallocation, and when you know how many elements you'll store, you can call `reserveCapacity` to pre-emptively reallocate and prevent intermediate reallocations.

Reading that, I'd say it's best to reserve the capacity you need, and only come back to optimize that if you find it's really a problem. You'll make more work for yourself if you're faking the length all the time.